# Web API 2 rest call first few calls are very slow if hasn't been called in a few minutes

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

This is very odd and have never heard of it. I have two rest web api 2 services running in IIS. Web Service A calls Web Service B and returns the contents of B (A acts as a facade).

If the web service has been idle for a few minutes, and I send a single request or a rapid burst of requests, the response time is about 10-20 seconds. After this, they return in milliseconds, even under high load.  However, if it receives no calls for a few minutes, then it goes slow again.

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that the Idle Timeout was set to 20 minutes which apparently means that if the web service isn't hit within 20 minutes. The service will actually be cleared from memory and have to respool